# How to reorder levels columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

this code is same my code except i have 300 columns, i need to reorder columns like this:
Total provit, Catgory ,numberofgoodsold for each company. it easy if i have few columns but as i said i have 300.

```
data = {'company': ['AMC', 'ER','CRR' , 'TYU'], 'Reg-ID': ['1222','2334','3444', '4566'], 'Total_provit': ['123300','12233', '3444444', '412222'], 'numberofgoodsold':['44','23','67','34'], Catgory: ['Tal','ERP','RTY close','ALL']}

d = pd.DataFrame(data)

d2 = d.pivot(index = 'Reg-ID', columns = 'company')

d2.columns = d2.columns.swaplevel(0, 1)
d2.sort_index(axis=1, level=0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Is `d2` supposed to be your starting point ? I do not see how `Reg-ID` could sanely be an indexer in the story. This somehow "squares up" your table with `NaN`s for no reason. I.e. it creates a block-diagonal table... But this may be out of your control... other non-dscientist colleagues' past work for example...

Comment: I didn't understand what are you saying. But I'm interested in ordering my columns. My columns are under each company in the same order. What I need is to reorder my columns for all companies in new order. I have 22 company under each one of it 8 columns. How I can change every 8 col for each company.  Did you get my idea?

Comment: Is `d2` supposed to be your starting point ? Addressing your point won't yield the same answer depending on whether we have to handle `d` or `d2`. You question is clear. What is not clear is the dataframe we have to start from.

Comment: d2 yes is my starting point. sorry

Comment: Do `d2.xs('TYU', axis=1, drop_level=False)` and you will see that you have `NaN`s everywhere, excepted for the last line. Do `d2.xs('AMC', axis=1, drop_level=False)`, idem with the first line. Why ? Because `Reg-ID` mirrors the same information as companies' names. So the question is: is `d2` really like this ? Or is it an attempt to provide us with a (wrongly formed) reproducible toy-object ?

Comment: sorry again. Reg-ID should be the same, as index, i meant the other columns.

Answer (score 1):

What about using [`pandas.DataFrame.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) as follows

```
>>> desired_order = ['Total_provit', 'Catgory', 'numberofgoodsold']
>>> d2.reindex(desired_order, level=1, axis=1)
company          AMC          ...     TYU                 
        Total_provit Catgory  ... Catgory numberofgoodsold
Reg-ID                        ...                         
1222          123300     Tal  ...     NaN              NaN
2334             NaN     NaN  ...     NaN              NaN
3444             NaN     NaN  ...     NaN              NaN
4566             NaN     NaN  ...     ALL               34
```

Comment: @Pythona you removed your comment, saying that this approach works. I guess that you still have questions ? Otherwise why not tick the answer as correct ?